# What happened to the holders of German war bonds after WW1?

Tags: war, economy, germany, world-war-one

I was just reading about how [Germany sold a lot of war bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_bond#Germany) to citizens and other entities during World War 1.

Given the dire economic situation of Germany after the war, what happened to the owners of these bonds? Did they mostly get reimbursed, or not?

Comment: Related: [What happened to the German WW II debt?](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/27069/17083)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Chickering](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8TTNfbKN5AUC&lpg=PP1&vq=war%20bond%20repayment&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=bond&f=false) suggests that bonds were seen as a patriotic sacrifice and they were nominally honoured but their value reduced by inflation:

> A war bond with a face value of 1,000 marks when purchased in the
>   summer of 1914 still carried a face value of 1,000 marks in the summer
>   of 1918, when its value, adjusted to current prices, stood close to
>   300 marks.

They could do this because they issued bonds in their own currency to a largely domestic audience and transitioned off the gold standard to a fiat currency during the war, as explained in [this article](http://encyclopedia.1914-1918-online.net/article/war_finance_germany).

Comment: So, this means that they were worth much less after the war. But can we deduce from this that they were mostly paid? Isn't it possible that they were both worth less *and* not paid?

Comment: @Fiksdal That is true. However, there would be no need to default when you can inflate the debt away. Indeed, during hyperinflation, the physical bond certificate may be worth more than the bond itself.